# Typescript Intellisense & syntax checking not working in Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, intellisense

This is proving very frustrating, the latest version & update of VS2017 Community has been installed. From my understanding the file `tsconfig.json` is not required, however in an attempt to get it working it has been created and the contents currently are :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
   "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true, 
    "noEmit": true
  },

  "typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true
  }    
}
```

As an example, I would expect when pressing the letter `s` as part of entering `var x:string;` a list of options be presented. This works correctly in VS Code.

No squiggly red lines appear for syntax checking.

In addition, saving the only typescript file in the project doesn't automatically build and create the Javascript file. Manually building the project does correctly create it.

Answer (score -1):

Go to *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Text Editor* -> *JavaScript/TypeScript* -> *Intellisense*.

Select a value in "*Use a Type Script Version:*" ComboBox.

[image: Visual Studio Options]